# Linux: write to a file with fields, keeping columns aligned

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write to a column aligned file (`/etc/fstab`) while keeping the file formatting.

The file contains:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Sat Feb 29 12:05:47 2020
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=388a99ed-9486-4a26-aeb6-06eaf6c47675 /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
```

and I am trying to add:

```
tmpfs  /dev/shm  tmpfs  defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec  0  0
```

However, the file could have more lines, implying a different number of spaces between fields. I want to write this line in a way that adapts to the file format, no matter the number of spaces between the fields.

What would be the recommended way to do it?

Comment: *the file could have more lines*, sure, apend it `echo "tmpfs  /dev/shm  tmpfs  defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec  0  0" >> /etc/fstab;`. *implying a different number of spaces between fields*, you dont need to parse it.

Comment: `more lines, implying a different number of spaces between fields` How does "count of lines" connect with "number of spaces between fields"? Can't I have two lines with different number of spaces? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212450/how-to-make-column-t-ignore-lines-with-specific-characteristics there you have even an example on fstab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Append the line not caring about the formatting.

```
echo 'tmpfs  /dev/shm  tmpfs  defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec  0  0' >> /etc/fstab
```

Step 2. Reformat the file. Take the script from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212450/how-to-make-column-t-ignore-lines-with-specific-characteristics

Remember to overwrite a file you need a temporary file. And with such method there's a bonus: Even if you write a field that is longer then the existing onces in fstab, `column -t` will resise all of them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

eg: change the following code accordingly...

```
cat file.txt | awk '{ printf ("%-6s   %5d %4s %3s  %4d    %8.3f%8.3f%8.3f \n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) }'
```

%-6s next column begins with the 6th string
spaces in the command matters
%8.3f mean flote with 3 decimals, d mean digit.
$1 $2 mean columns by spaces

Comment: `%5d` why? `%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f` why? This is fstab - second field is path, and there are max 6 fields (unless, there is something I do not know about).

Comment: oh it is something I used in my files.. never mind, in my file it contains three flotes

Comment: You don't need `cat`. Just redirect file to `awk` directly

Answer (score 0):

You could use `echo -e` and `tab` (instead of spaces).
For Tab you put `\t` and for new line you put `\n`
Say I want to add these two lines to a file:

```
somthing    /foo/bar    defaults    0    0
anotherthing    /bar/foo    sync,defaults    0    0
```

The command will be like this:

```
echo -e "somthing\t/foo/bar\tdefaults\t0\t0\nanotherthing\t/bar/foo\tsync,defaults\t0\t0" >> file
```

Don't forget double quots `""` :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However your solution generates an output which is not aligned to the first line. For example, there would be an equivalent of 7 spaces between the last two "0" instead of one space.